# Set the font in winforms designer to a Font object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, fonts

I'm working on a project in Windows Forms and I want to use custom fonts for buttons etc.

I have a static class that contains the styles of fonts that I want. For example:

```
ParagraphFont = new Font(Properties.Resources.Font, 14.25F);
TitleFont = new Font(Properties.Resources.Font, 48, FontStyle.Bold);
```

I want to be able to apply the font to the form/user control through the designer, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I've tried setting the fonts of all the controls to these variables after the InitialiseComponent() method, but this seems long-winded and tedious to do to the multiple forms and controls that my project has

Is there a quicker way of doing this?

**Edit:** My question is different to the suggested duplicate. I don't need to set the default font of the project, I want to set the font of each control individually to a style variable. For example:

```
label.Font = ParagraphFont;
```

In the designer. This way, I can change the font used in ParagraphFont at any time

Comment: @John not really, I'm looking for a way of setting the font to be part of a style set

Comment: OK, retracted my suggestion :) Note that reassigning `ParagraphFont` wouldn't automatically update `label.Font` - only updating properties of the existing `Font` instance would be reflected (because `Font` is a reference type, `label.Font = ParagraphFont` means that they both point at the same instance).

Comment: You could implement a specialized class object that implement the [IExtenderProvider Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider), like a ToolTip. An Extender Provider class adds properties in the Designer to all Controls that can extend their Properties. You can then modify a Control's Font and Style using a Font list provided by your extender class.

Comment: That sounds promising. I'll do some research on that and implement it if needed @Jimi